# How to use Node WPAPI with Wordpress.com (endpoint)?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, wp-api

I'm trying to figure out how to use [Node WPAPI](https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi) with a Wordpress.com-hosted blog.

```
const wp = new WPAPI({
  endpoint: 'https://MYSITE.wordpress.com/wp-json'
})
const posts = await wp.posts().get()
console.log(`posts:`, posts)
```

But I'm getting “Not Found” errors (if I set the Wordpress privacy to "Private" I get no error!).

I'm used to interacting with Wordpress REST API at https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/MYSITE.wordpress.com/posts but the `/wp-json` route doesn't seem to be available.

What to do?

### Update

Seems that the v2 API endpoint is `https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/MYSITE.wordpress.com` but now I get this error:

```
{ code: 'rest_no_route',
  message: 'No route was found matching the URL and request method.' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close, the endpoint was:

```
https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/MYSITE.wordpress.com/{resource}
```

e.g:

```
https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/MYSITE.wordpress.com/posts
```